# How to avoid nul value in URL in android?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a strange issue about using Retrofit2 in my android project. I got the issue about the server error since the request is something like that.

https://www.example.com/api/v1/skills?q=Good%00

Since the invalid value "%00" is not acceptable in our server, so it showed error on my activity.

API service

```
@GET("skills")
Observable<SearchItem> getSkills(@Query("q") String keyword);
```

In my fragment, I just get the text using following simple statement.

```
String keyword = editText.getText().toString()
api.getSkills(keyword);
```

What I want to know is the following:

1. Is it possible to have a word can be converted to "%00" ?
2. How to avoid this "Good%00" before I send to `getSkills` function?

Comment: use keyword.trim() to trim leading and trailing spaces and use some validation before sending string to server

Comment: Use .replace() method and replace it with something else and then send it to server.

Comment: @Yesha ShahDid you mean I should use something like "GoodNUL".replace("NUL","") to avoid it to be like "Good%00"?

Comment: @LongRanger I guess it will be better if you use urlencoder..
final String encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode("Good%00", "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/api/v1/skills?q="+encodedURL);

Answer (score 0):

To enable compile time checks on nullity add `@NonNull` annotation,

```
@GET("skills")
Observable<SearchItem> getSkills(@NonNull @Query("q") String keyword);
```

Another way is to change each  `"%00"` in your string, using `.replace()`

Comment: Is it also work if the value is "Good%00" ? Actually, the server error occurred when the parameter contained "%00" value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use  [**`trim()`**](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-trim)

> The java string trim() method eliminates leading and trailing spaces. The unicode value of space character is '\u0020'. The trim() method in java string checks this unicode value before and after the string, if it exists then removes the spaces and returns the omitted string.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
String keyword = editText.getText().toString().trim();
api.getSkills(keyword)
```

or your can use

[**`replace()`**](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace)

> The java string replace() method returns a string replacing all the old char or `CharSequence` to new char or `CharSequence`.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
url =url.replace("%00", "");
```

or You can use [**`URLEncoder`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

> Utility class for HTML form encoding. This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format. For more information about HTML form encoding

```
String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(yourURL,"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the string with `""` if it contains `%00`

```
if (text.toString().contains("%00")){
 text = text.replace("%00", "");
}
```

and then call `getSkills(text)` with updated value

Answer (score 0):

```
There is two way to solve this

1. you restrict the entry write below code

android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

you can add more thing which you want

String keyword = editText.getText().toString().replace("%00", "");
api.getSkills(keyword);
```